# Silex login and retrieve ID

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have the basic Silex login process up and running with the user coming from the database.

The database table I use contains some more information that I want to be readily available for the logged in session, but I can't find "where to put it". The Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User only has a few fields for username, password, salt, but provides no method to store more information against the object.

The alternative I thought was to store the data in separate db tables, however I am unable to retrieve the ID of the database row of the currently logged in user, so I cannot even link other tables to the user. I am a little reluctant to have both a user table and another table using the 'username' as an identifier.

I must be doing something wrong, just need a little help.

Update: I should add I used the UserProvider detailed here:
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom User class in your UserProvider

```
// UserProvider file
<?php
namespace X;
use YourNamespace/YourCustomUser;

...
public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
    ...
    return YourCustomUser(...);
}
```

Note that according to http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider YourCustomUser should implement Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface:

```
// YourCustomUser file
<?php
...
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
...
class YourCustomUser implements UserInterface {
    /* add custom properties here, e.g. phone_number */
}
```